# How to render collection with template in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If there is a _post.html.erb in app/views/posts/, I can input `<%= render @posts %>` in app/views/posts/index.html.erb , but if the _post.html.erb file in app/views/users/posts/, how to write?

I tried `<%= render @posts, :template => 'users/posts/post' %>` , but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= render :partial => 'users/posts/post', :collection => @posts %>
```